# Exercise 3.1 in Brezis' Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show you an exercise similar to Brezis 3.1 :

**Let $E$ be a Normed space and let $A \subset E$ be a subset that is compact for the weak topology of $E$. Prove that $A$ is bounded**

At Brezis he considers $E$ a Banach space, that would come out using Banach-Steinhaus theorem. I cannot see this result for normed space.

Comment: $A$ is also weakly compact in  the completion of $E$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, what is completion of E?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It would be $E^C$ in relation to A?

Comment: Any normed linear space is densely embedded in a Banach space.

Answer (score 2):

If $(E,\|\;\|_E)$ is a normed space, then there is a Banach space $(X,\|\;\|_X)$ and and a linear isometry $\iota: E\rightarrow X$ such that $\iota(E)$ is dense in $X$,  $(X,\iota)$ is  called the Hausdorff completion of $E$, and is  unique up to isomorphisms.

Being an isometry, $\iota$ is continuous and so $\iota(A)$ is a compact subset  of $X$.    Since a set $B\subset E$ is bounded in $(E,\|\;\|_E)$ iff $\iota(B)$ is bounded in $(X,\|\;\|_E)$, it suffices to assume that $(E,\|\;\|_E)$ is a Banach space to begin with  for the purpose of the OP.

---

***Comment:*** A standard contraction of ons such completion is through Cauchy sequence in $E$. Let $\mathcal{C}_E$ denote the collection of all sequences $\boldsymbol{a}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow E$ that are Cauchy in the $(E,\|\;\|_E)$. For each $x\in E$, the constant sequence $\overline{x}(n)=x$ defines an element of $\mathcal{C}_E$; hence $\mathcal{C}_E$ *contains* $E$. The sum and scalar product on $E$ extend to $\mathcal{C}_E$ in the obvious way:
$(\boldsymbol{a}+\boldsymbol{b})(n)=\boldsymbol{a}(n)+\boldsymbol{b}(n)$ and $(c\boldsymbol{a})(n)=c \,\boldsymbol{a}(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

On $\mathcal{C}_E$ define
$$\rho(\boldsymbol{a})=\lim_n \|\boldsymbol{a}(n)\|_E$$
Notice that $\rho$ is well defined, for
$\big|\|\boldsymbol{a}(n)\|_E-\|\boldsymbol{a}(m)\|_E\big|\leq \|\boldsymbol{a}(n)-\boldsymbol{a}(m)\|_E$
Hence $(\|\boldsymbol{a}(n)\|_E:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
It easy to check that  $\rho$ is a pseudo-norm, that is $\rho$ satisfies all the properties of norm except for $\rho(\boldsymbol{a})=0$ does not imply $\boldsymbol{a}=\boldsymbol{0}:=\overline{0}$. It is easy to check that the relation $\boldsymbol{a}\sim\boldsymbol{b}$ iff $\rho(\boldsymbol{a}-\boldsymbol{b})=0$ is an equivalence relation and then, $\mathcal{C}_E/\sim$ with
$$\overline{\rho}([\boldsymbol{a}]):=\rho(\boldsymbol{a})$$
where $[\boldsymbol{a}]$ is the equivalence class of $\boldsymbol{a}\in\mathcal{C}_E$ is a normed space.

The map $\iota:E\mapsto \mathcal{C}_E/\sim$ given by $x\mapsto[\overline{x}]$ is a linear isometry and $\iota(E)$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}_E/\sim$. Indeed, if $x\in E$ then
$\|\overline{x}(n)\|_X=\|x\|_E$ for all $n\in\mathbb{B}$ and so, $\rho(\iota(x))=\rho([\overline{x}])=\|x\|_E$. Now, suppose $Y\in \mathcal{C}_E/\sim$, and let $\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathcal{C}_E$ be a representative of $Y$, that is $Y=[\boldsymbol{y}]$. Define $y_n:=\boldsymbol{y}(n)$ and consider $\iota(y_n)=[\overline{y_n}]$. Since $\boldsymbol{y}$ is Cauchy, for $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|\boldsymbol{y}(n)-\boldsymbol{y}(m)\|_X<\varepsilon$ whenever $n,m\geq N_\varepsilon$. Hence, for $n\geq N_\varepsilon$
$$\rho([\overline{y}_n]-[\boldsymbol{y}])=\rho([\overline{y_n}-\boldsymbol{y}])=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\|\boldsymbol{y}(n)-\boldsymbol{y}(m)\|_E\leq\varepsilon$$
This shows that $\iota(E)$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}_E/\sim$.

Finally, we show that$(\mathcal{C}_E/\sim, \overline{\rho})$ is a Banach space. It only remains to check that $\rho$ is a complete norm. Suppose $(Y_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{C}_E/\sim$. For each $n\in\mathbb{B}$ choose $x_n\in E$ such that $\rho(\iota(x_n),Y_n)<\frac{1}{n}$. It follows that $(\iota(x_n):n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{C}_E/\sim$ for
\begin{align}
\rho(\iota(x_n)-\iota(x_m))&\leq \rho(\iota(x_n)-Y_n)+\rho(Y_n-Y_m)+\rho(Y_m-\iota(x_m))\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\rho(Y_n-Y_m)
\end{align}
Since $\rho(\iota(x_n)-\iota(y_m))=\|x_n-x_m\|_E$, the sequence $\boldsymbol{x}$ defined as $\boldsymbol{x}(n)=x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$, that is $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathcal{C}_E$. It follows that $\iota(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}X=[\boldsymbol{x}]$. Indeed, for $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$\|x_n-x_m\|_E<\varepsilon$ whenever $n,m\geq N_\varepsilon$. Hence, for all $n\geq N_\varepsilon$
$$\rho(\iota(x_n)-X)=\lim_m\|x_n-\boldsymbol{x}(m)\|_E=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\|x_n-x_m\|\leq\varepsilon$$
This completes the proof of the existence of Hasudorff's completion of a normed space. $\Box$

To prove uniqueness up-to isometry, suppose $(Y,\|\,\|_Y)$ is another Banach space, and $j:E\rightarrow Y$ an norm-isometry such that $j(E)$ is dense in $Y$. Denote by $(X,\|\;\|_X)=(\mathcal{C}_E/\sim,\rho)$. Define $T:\iota(X)\mapsto j(X)$ by $\iota(x)\mapsto j(x)$. This map is well defined since $\iota$ and $j$ are injective. Since $\|T(\iota(x))\|_Y=\|j(x)\|_Y=\|x\|_E=\|\iota(y)\|_X$, $T$ and its inverse $T^{-1}$ are isometries. Thus they $T$ and $T^{-1}$ can be extended as isometries to $X$ and $Y$ respectively. It is easy to check that the $T\circ T^{-1}=I_Y$ and $T^{-1}\circ T=I_X$. $\Box$

---

To complete the problem,  we use $\|\;\|$ to denote the norm $\|\;\|_E$, and assume that $(E,\|\;\|)$ is a Banach space to begin with.  Let $E^*$ denote the  duals space of $E$ and denote by $\|\;\|_*$ the dual norm, that is
$$\|\lambda\|^*=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\lambda x|$$
Recall that the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$ on $E$ is has local basis given by sets of the form
$$
V(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n;\varepsilon):=\{x\in E: |\lambda_jx|<\varepsilon\}$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in E^*$, and $\varepsilon>0$.

If $A$ is $\sigma(E,E^*)$-compact (weakly compact), then it is also $\sigma(E,E^*)$-bounded. Then, for any $\lambda\in E^*$, there is $c_\lambda>0$ such that
$A\subset c_\lambda V(\lambda;1)=\{x\in E: |\lambda x|<c\}$
That is, for any $\lambda\in E^*$
$$\sup_{x\in A}|\lambda x|<\infty$$
For any $x\in E$ define $\hat{x}\in (E^*)^*$ as the linear functional
$$\hat{x}(\lambda)=\lambda x, \qquad \lambda \in E^*$$
By the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, the linear functionals $\{\hat{x}:x\in A\}\subset (E^*)^*$ are uniformly bounded, i.e.,
$$\sup_{x\in A}\|\hat{x}\|_{**}<\infty$$
where
$$\|\hat{x}\|_{**}=\sup_{\|\lambda\|_*=1}|\hat{x}(\lambda)|=\sup_{\|\lambda\|_*=1}|\lambda x|$$
Recall that from the Hahn-Banach theorem,
$$\|x\|=\sup_{\|\lambda\|_*=1}|\lambda x|$$
Hence $\sup_{x\in A}\|x\|<\infty$ and so, $A$ is bounded in $(E,\|\;\|)$.